# Lagrange Duality Derivation question

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, lagrange-multiplier

I'm trying to understand the Lagrange Duality problem and got stuck here.

[image: Lagrange Duality]

My question is why the partial derivative of $L$ with respect to $b$ is $\sum(\alpha_i  y_i)$. I tried and I got $\sum(-\alpha_i  y_i)$.

Can someone please show me the exact derivation steps?

Comment: You have it right. But it's an expression you need to set to $0$. So the minus sign can be discarded. ;)

Comment: Sorry it's probably very obvious to you but I still don't quite understand your point. I can get to sum(-αi * yi)=0, how can we get rid of the 0?

Comment: It's not getting rid of the zero. What you're doing there is similar to what you might do to minimize a function. You're taking the partial derivative and setting it to $0$. So once you do $\sum -\alpha_i y_i = 0$, all you need to do next is discard the $-$, and get  $\sum \alpha_i y_i = 0$ as they do in the text.

Comment: @learning thanks. I got it now.